# Why can't I integrate the Java templating system Pebble?

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, intellij-idea

[It looks so simple](https://pebbletemplates.io/wiki/guide/spring-boot-integration/)

My `pom.xml` has:

```
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-public</id>
            <name>Sonatype Public</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
```

and

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pebbletemplates</groupId>
            <artifactId>pebble-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

then I `rm -rf ~/.m2/repository` and `mvn clean package compile` but obviously still this bit of Kotlin is invalid:

```
package au.com.ngv.mystream.trove.view

val pebbleEngine = PebbleEngine.Builder().build()
```

**HOWEVER** I would expect IntelliJ after *File / Invalidate caches ...* to know what `PebbleEngine` is and suggest the right package to import, but IntelliJ shows `PebbleEngine` in red and offers only to create the class declaration.  It does not offer to add the import declaration, which shows that it doesn't know from where `PebbleEngine` comes.

So why is it that after doing all that the Pebble documents say, I cannot use the package?

Comment: Try to click on `Reload All Maven Projects` in Maven tool window. (https://prnt.sc/VkZ5vZ7Hhnl7)

Comment: To make it work automatically you can switch from `External Changes` to `Any Changes` under `Settings / Preferences (on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools`.

Comment: Thanks Egor for replying.  As I needed only a small subset of `PebbleEngine`s functionality, I decided before you replied just to roll my own solution.